# Android onPause and onResume Method

Tags: android

Am trying to implementent `onPause()` and `onResume()`, such that when am out of the activity the the text in my text view is still there, but its displaying `"null"` when i start the the activity please assist!

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        etPassenger.setText(""+ gotPassenger );
        etStaffNumber.setText("" + gotStaffNumber);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        etPassenger.setText(""+ gotPassenger );
        etStaffNumber.setText("" + gotStaffNumber);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to save your data even when closing your app you need to use `sharedPreferences`. Here's how you use them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/2649104

Answer (score 0):

I think `gotPassenger` and `gotStaffNumber` vars are null - if you want to save them than you have to use prefs or save them to some bundle to restore later.

Answer (score 0):

When you are minimizing your activity your variables becoming null.
Add the following code in your activity,

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
savedInstanceState.putString("gotPassenger",gotPassenger);
savedInstanceState.putString("gotStaffNumber",gotStaffNumber);
}
```

And, in your onCreate() method, add the following,

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
etPassenger.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("gotPassenger"));
etStaffNumber.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("gotStaffNumber"));
}
```

Comment: I hope you are closing the entire application.
Then use `SharedPreferences` to store the values of gotPassenger and gotStaffNumber.
Here's a tutorial for using `SharedPreferences`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Answer (score 0):

When you are leaving your activity, you will loose the data stored inside gotPassenger and gotStaffNumber.
If you want to reuse them after exiting your application, you have to use `SharedPreferences` to save them first and retrieve them when you are back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your data even when closing your app you need to use `sharedPreferences`. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/2649104) how you use them